# showing error generated by validation actionform data separately in struts

Tags: hibernate, spring, validation, struts

i am developing a web application using struts, spring and hibernate. One point to be clear first: the code level is limited to jdk1.4.
i want to validate inputs from user (actionForm) and store the updates to database through hibernate. I am now using Struts Validation framework to validate the correctness of the form's inputs. The problems is i want to have each error message located next/below to the corresponding input field in the jsp rather than to generated by struts tag  which is a . Any help?
ps. any other validation framework that accomplish what i want would be welcome too, as i have not implement the validation yet

Answer (score 0):

The [`<html:errors>`](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#html%3aerrors) tag takes a property attribute. If given, it only displays the errors for the given property. Just put this tag with the appropriate property next to the field, and you'll have what you want.

Comment: I put the following code in my JSP `<html:errors property="username" />`  It shows the error message in a bullet.  How can I get rid of the bullet without using CSS?

Comment: This is explained in the documentation of the tag, which I linked to in my answer. It comes from the default header, footer, prefix and suffix. An alternative is also proposed in the documentation.